# PostScript viewer for Mac

Tags: gratis, osx, postscript

I am looking for a PostScript viewer for Mac.

It must be a GUI program with a relatively convenient interface.  I only need to view single page EPS files, no need for multi-page general PostScript.

I am looking for something else than Preview, which converts PostScript to PDF before viewing and often messes it up in the process.  Perhaps something GhostScript based.

Answer (score 2):

**I found `gv`, which is available in MacPorts.**  Note that it requires [X](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/), so it won't do retina resolution.  The user interface is a bit archaic, but very usable after getting used to it.  Don't let it scare you away. **Recommended.**

---

I do *not* recommend:

- [MacGhostView](http://www.kiffe.com/macghostview.html) because it appears to be the same as `gv`, packaged into an app, for a charge.
- Gnome GhostView (`ggv` in MacPorts) install failed with MacPorts, plus it depends on much of the Gnome system, which is a lot of unnecessary software to install just to view EPS files.
- `yap-app` from MacPorts failed to install again due to its GnuStep dependency.
- MacGSView is outdated and won't work on recent OS X.

I hope this will help others avoid wasting time trying PostScript viewers that won't work.